# Invoices - which country do I ask about tax?

Tags: taxes

I am freelancing for a German company and am a British student studying in the UK.

I have to gain info for an invoice (invoice number, purchase order number, info about my status as a 'freelancer'). Do I ask the German or UK tax office for this?

Comment: You pay taxes where **you live** not where clients live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items of information you mention will not be given to you by any tax office.  You seem to have misunderstood how this works.

The Invoice Number is something that you generate and give to your customer.
The Purchase Order Number is something that your customer will generate and give to you.
Your status as a Freelancer is something that you must tell the tax office.

In the UK you would tell the HMRC when completing your annual [Self-Assessment](https://www.gov.uk/topic/personal-tax/self-assessment).  Just fill in the form.